# If I get an HND then a BSc, can I then go and specialise in any area for my Masters?

Tags: masters, university, united-kingdom

I am currently in an apprenticeship for Software Development; however, I want to change my future career after doing a job as a Software Developer.

I would like to know if I would be able to go and do a MSc in Astronautics if I get a HND in Engineering and the do the top-up course for the Bachelor's Degree. I didn't get the best GSCEs although I do have my 5 C's and did not do any A-levels. Would this still be possible?

For anybody wondering, I live in the UK.

Comment: As long as you have an engineering BSc (with grades that are not just all barely passing) in hand when you apply for the austronautics/aeronautics/aerospace engineering MSc, there isn't anything standing in your way **in principle**. I would say that you should definitely go for it! However, you should also keep in mind that it will involve a significant amount of math and physics - so be prepared.

Comment: @StrangeLoop I am well aware of the physics and maths of the course and will absolutely apply every single part of me to pass. Thank you for the advice, I appreciate it!

Comment: For the non-UKians: HND = Higher National Diploma. Roughly equivalent to completing the 2nd year of a UK Bachelor's degree.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are several routes to get to your speciality Masters. Once you've got your Bachelor's degree, very few people will care much about the route you took to get it, whether it was an HND, foundation course, A-levels at night school, whatever.

Comment: Awesome. I was worried I would still need the appropriate A-levels or GCSEs for the course. Thanks for the answer